# Is it possible to show a Partial enum in a custom inspector in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums

Is there a way to only have certain enum values available in the inspector? For example I have an enum full of objects, and if I select table I want a second enum with specific object ids to only show table1/table2/table3 instead of all the available objects.

```
public enum Objects
{
    Chair,
    Table,
    Door
}

public enum ObjectIDs
{
    Chair01, 
    Chair02,
    Table01,
    Table02,
    Table03,
    etc..
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can use `Enum.GetNames` for receive the entire list of `ObjectIDs`'s name an than filter using the name of your selected `Objects` value and than using `Enum.GetValue`  passing each of the filtered name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very robust plugin which makes that kind of things very easy.

https://odininspector.com/attributes/show-if-attribute

Answer (score 0):

you can modify [this code](https://forum.unity.com/threads/enum-inspector-sorting-attribute.357558/) to make what you want.

You need to change the `EnumOrderDrawer` class to make the loops not go for all the `enum` variables.

For example change the code

```
public const string TypeOrder = "10,1,5,2";
public enum Type 
    {
        One = 10,
        Two = 1,
        Three = 5,
        Four = 2,
    }

    [EnumOrder(TypeOrder)]
    public Type type3;
.
.
.
.
for (int i=0; i<property.enumNames.Length; i++) 
        {
             items[i] = property.enumNames[indexArray[i]];
        }
```

to

```
public const int[] TypeOrder = new int[] { 10, 1, 5, 2 };
public enum Type 
    {
        One = 10,
        Two = 1,
        Three = 5,
        Four = 2,
    }

    [EnumOrder(TypeOrder)]
    public Type type3;
.
.
.
.
for (int i=0; i<TypeOrder.Length; i++) 
        {
             items[i] = property.enumNames[indexArray[i]];
        }
.
.
.
.
```